# How to automatically adjust an Org task state with its children checkboxes

Tags: org-mode

I have several tasks in my Org file, one of which has items starting with a checkbox (but only those). They all have a statistic cookie at their end ([n/m]).

I'm looking for a way to automatically update the parent task from `TODO` to `DONE` once all of the checkboxes are marked as done as well.

The documentation says:

> If you would like a TODO entry to automatically change to DONE when all children are done, you can use the following setup [...]
>
> Another possibility is the use of checkboxes to identify (a hierarchy of) a large number of subtasks (see Checkboxes).

The way I understand that last part is that if children items are checkboxes, parent state should already be automatically updated (which is not the case).

What am I missing?

---

**Edit:**

From `org-after-todo-statistics-hook`'s documentation (org.el):

> Hook that is called after a TODO statistics cookie has been updated.
>   Each function is called with two arguments: the number of not-done entries
>   and the number of done entries.

Which means that the proposed code from orgmode.org:

```el
(defun org-summary-todo (n-done n-not-done)
  "Switch entry to DONE when all subentries are done, to TODO otherwise."
  (let (org-log-done org-log-states)   ; turn off logging
    (org-todo (if (= n-not-done 0) "DONE" "TODO"))))

(add-hook 'org-after-todo-statistics-hook 'org-summary-todo)
```

won't count checkbox items.

Comment: Do you have a statistics cookie in the headline?  Like this: `* Heading [0/1]`

Comment: Yes, there is. Forgot to mention that bit my bad.

Comment: I think this misunderstanding comes from the org manual not being so clear in this case. The line that starts "Another possibility is the use of checkboxes..." is a new paragraph under the heading "Breaking tasks down into subtasks". I *think* that "another possibility" in this case is referring to another possibility for breaking tasks into subtasks *not* another possibility for automatically changing the TODO state. Maybe try their suggested function and hook (though I couldn't get this to wokr)

Comment: @elethan It actually makes sense, I guess. Yes see my edit :)

Comment: This is a [FAQ](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-hacks.html#mark-done-when-all-checkboxes-checked).

Answer (score 7):

As you mentioned in your updated question, `org-after-todo-statistics-hook` isn't what you want. What you want is `org-checkbox-statistics-hook`.

I use this function to do what you describe (they should really get this functionality into org-mode):

```
(defun my/org-checkbox-todo ()
  "Switch header TODO state to DONE when all checkboxes are ticked, to TODO otherwise"
  (let ((todo-state (org-get-todo-state)) beg end)
    (unless (not todo-state)
      (save-excursion
    (org-back-to-heading t)
    (setq beg (point))
    (end-of-line)
    (setq end (point))
    (goto-char beg)
    (if (re-search-forward "\\[\\([0-9]*%\\)\\]\\|\\[\\([0-9]*\\)/\\([0-9]*\\)\\]"
                   end t)
        (if (match-end 1)
        (if (equal (match-string 1) "100%")
            (unless (string-equal todo-state "DONE")
              (org-todo 'done))
          (unless (string-equal todo-state "TODO")
            (org-todo 'todo)))
          (if (and (> (match-end 2) (match-beginning 2))
               (equal (match-string 2) (match-string 3)))
          (unless (string-equal todo-state "DONE")
            (org-todo 'done))
        (unless (string-equal todo-state "TODO")
          (org-todo 'todo)))))))))
```

`(add-hook 'org-checkbox-statistics-hook 'my/org-checkbox-todo)` will it call it every time you toggle a checkbox.

It does require you have a statistics cookie (the thing you get with `[/]` or `[%]` then `C-c C-c`) in the header.

Comment: Do you happen to have a version that, when the TODO is scheduled to repeat, unchecks the checklist for the scheduling again? :)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a version that does what @ctietze is looking for--toggle the checkbox state for items in the checklist. I tried calling `org-reset-checkbox-state-subtree` but got errors about too many nested frames (I'm using Spacemacs).

Here is my working solution:

```
    (defun my/org-reset-checkbox-state-subtree ()
    "Simplified version of org-list builtin"
    ;; Begin copy from org-reset-checkbox-subtree
    (org-narrow-to-subtree)
      (org-show-subtree)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (let ((end (point-max)))
        (while (< (point) end)
          (when (org-at-item-checkbox-p)
            (replace-match "[ ]" t t nil 1))
          (beginning-of-line 2)))
      (org-update-checkbox-count-maybe 'all)
    ;; End copy from org-reset-checkbox-subtree
    )

  (defun my/org-checkbox-todo ()
    "Switch header TODO state to DONE when all checkboxes are ticked, to TODO otherwise"
    (let ((todo-state (org-get-todo-state)) beg end)
      (unless (not todo-state)
        (save-excursion
          (org-back-to-heading t)
          (setq beg (point))
          (end-of-line)
          (setq end (point))
          (goto-char beg)
          (if (re-search-forward "\\[\\([0-9]*%\\)\\]\\|\\[\\([0-9]*\\)/\\([0-9]*\\)\\]"
                                 end t)
              (if (match-end 1)
                  (if (equal (match-string 1) "100%")
                      (unless (string-equal todo-state "DONE")
                        (my/org-reset-checkbox-state-subtree)
                        (org-todo 'done))
                    (unless (string-equal todo-state "TODO")
                      (org-todo 'todo)))
                (if (and (> (match-end 2) (match-beginning 2))
                         (equal (match-string 2) (match-string 3)))
                    (unless (string-equal todo-state "DONE")
                      (my/org-reset-checkbox-state-subtree)
                      (org-todo 'done))
                  (unless (string-equal todo-state "TODO")
                    (org-todo 'todo)))))))))
  (add-hook 'org-checkbox-statistics-hook 'my/org-checkbox-todo)
```